# MySQL multiple SELECT statement count results returned per table

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to select 3 tables at once for a query.  I would like to know what is the best way to determine how many rows are returned for each table?

Doing this individually, I have

```
SELECT * from tableA  
SELECT * from tableB  
SELECT * from tableC
```

If I do it this way, I can see on each select how many rows are returned.  I would like to select all these at once which I've done successfully, but I'd like to know how to pick up results per table returned.  Example query below:

```
SELECT * from tableA ta WHERE id=100  
SELECT * from tableB tb where pid=100  
SELECT * from tableC tc where cid = 100
```

Is it just a matter of doing this?

```
SELECT (count(id) from tableA where id=100) as count_tableA,  
SELECT * from tableA ta WHERE id=100,    
SELECT (count(pid) from tableB where id=100) as count_tableB,   
SELECT * from tableB tb where pid=100,  
SELECT (count(id) from tableB where cid=100) as count_tableC,  
SELECT * from tableC tc where cid = 100
```

The overall goal is to increase performance by avoiding 3 queries each time, but with that, I need to isolate how many rows to pick up from each table that is returned.

Comment: Are you joining the tables together in some way?

Comment: What are you using to run the query? Most Db drivers supports some sort of 'count of returned rows'

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin.  @GreenDemon, those queries are my method for joining, and they work fine, I just want to confirm that this is the most efficient way for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't really avoid the queries.  You have to query each table to get the rows, and that requires a full-table scan.

You can optimize the counts by creating indexes on `tableA(id)`, `tableB(id)`, and `tableC(cid)`.

You can also fetch the rows in your application layer, and then do the count afterwards.

The syntax for your query is not correct.  Perhaps you mean:

```
select (SELECT count(id) from tableA where id=100) as count_tableA,  a.*
from TableA
where id = 100;
```

And so on.